# Turning the values in an array of objects into their own key value pair object and inserting into the new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am new to Typescript/Javascript and I am having trouble manipulating an array of data so I apologize in advance for my incompetency.

Given an array of objects with values such:

```
items = [{header: "h1", value: "header 1 test"}, {header: "h2", value: "header 2 test"}]
```

I want to be able to loop through each object in the array and take their values and turn them into a key:value pair object and insert that into a new array that should look like this.

```
myNewArray = [{"h1": "header 1 test"}, {"h2": "header 2 test"}]
```

I am working with Angular and TypeScript but I believe both Javascript and Typescript should work. Feel free to use any modern techniques.
I have tried creating a new array, using ES6 [element.header]: [element.value] and it still giving me trouble.

Thanks!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const items = [{header: "h1", value: "header 1 test"}, {header: "h2", value: "header 2 test"}];

const result = items.map(el => ({[el.header]: el.value}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as intended except the result is:

result = [{h1: "header 1 test"}, {h2: "header 2 test"}]

Is there any way to get the property into a string during the map conversion?

i.e   
result = [{"h1": "header 1 test"}, {"h2: "header 2 test"}]

Comment: This is an array of objects, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operator on an array. In code this would look like this:

```
const myNewArray = items.map((item) => {
    const header = item.header;
    const value = item.value;

    return {
        [header]: value
    };
});
```

The `map` operator will loop through your array and call the defined function for each element. You can then transform the element to whatever value you want and the `map` operator will group them together into a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing tricky here is the need to use () to wrap the object you return in a map

```js
const newObj = [{header: "h1", value: "header 1 test"}, {header: "h2", value: "header 2 test"}]
.map(item => ({[item.header]:item.value}))

console.log(newObj)
```